# understanding the the benefit of generics over typecasting?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a couple of ways to get a value from a config file, that contains various types.

I'm trying to understand the benefits of using a generic vs typecasting.

on the caller side I could do a simple cast:
`const botToken = AppConfig.getenv('botToken') as string`
vs
`const botToken = AppConfig.getenv<string>('botToken')`

On the API provider side the basic yolo `any` way

```
export class AppConfig {
    static getenv(key: configKey): any {
 ...
```

vs

```
export class AppConfig {
    static getenv<T extends any>(key: string, env?: string): T {
```

The question is:
Does the generic method do any extra checking for example to test that given a key of X the return type is the same as the requested type in ?
Or is it effectively just typecasting the results to what I asked for in  in order to pass the compile checks?

Perhaps this isn't a good use case because there are so many different types and data structures this API could return... so i'm still using `T extends any` for the definition.

I'm also type checking the key param that is passed, given I have some knowledge of the shape of the Config env data:

```
export interface ConfigVars {
    prefixes?: string[];
    port?: number;
    network?: string;
    alchemyApi?: AlchemyConfig;
}
export type configKey = keyof ConfigVars
```

ref:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types

Answer (score 1):

I think in your use case it will not have direct benefits.

The indirect one I can think of: You can disallow type assertions generally (e.g. via linter) and still happily use the generic version.

As this looks like a config value, it is likely impossible to have this 100% type checked at compile time.